# RBS Background assertion ERROR while using WKWebview IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, assertion

I'm using a wkwebview. On some action on the webpage, i give control to my app, and then i pass over the data to the webview again.
During this delegation process, my webview is in the background over which another view controller is presenting.

When i communicate back to my webview, i get the following error message and then the webview crashes.

RBS Background assertion ‘ConnectionTerminationWatchdog’ for process because PID is invalid[Process] 0x11630be18 - [pageProxyID=14, webPageID=15, PID=3281] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 3281), reason 3
assertion]

Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 “Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing” UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:“com.apple.webkit” name:“Background” sourceEnvironment:“(null)“>,

NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
2021-11-26 09:51:46.441022-0500 PinThatPoint[3274:637929] [ProcessSuspension] 0x127cb42c0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion ‘WebProcess Background Assertion’ for process with PID 3281,

I have searched the internet, but it's silent on the solution.